# Dataweave: How to concatenate values for a certain key in json array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My input is

```
[
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "FirstName": "ALEX",
    "LastName": "JOHNSON"
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "FirstName": "BOB",
    "LastName": "BROWN"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "FirstName": "JANE",
    "LastName": "DOE"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "JOHN",
    "LastName": "SMITH"
  },
  {
    "Id": 6,
    "FirstName": "JOHN",
    "LastName": "WILKINS"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "FirstName": "TIMOTHY",
    "LastName": "WALTERS"
  }
]
```

Output I want is a string concatenating all the FirstName values in the order in which they are listed in the input

```
"ALEX, BOB, JANE, JOHN, JOHN, TIMOTHY"
```

I'm new to Dataweave and not sure how to do this

 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try it with the use of descendant selector

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload..FirstName joinBy ","
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to first map each element into the FirstName value only then use the joinBy() function to concatenate them separate by a comma:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map $.FirstName joinBy  ", "
```

You can alternatively use the reduce() function.